# Idk if my ide is bugging or what but i need help pls

Tags: string, cs50

Okay so i've been taking the cs50 EDX course and have been using their ide. I went on today and put in very easy code just to see if I remember. I don't know if I'm just dumb or what but when I put this code in I get  an error saying: "format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'string *' (aka 'char **') [-Werror,-Wformat]
scanf("%s", &name);"

I have other code that has similar almost alike code and it works just fine. Please help, that would very much be appreciated.(i am a beginner)

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    string name;
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    printf("Hello %s", name);
}
```

Copied code from youtube that doesnt work for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[10];
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    printf("Hello %s", name);
}
```

Comment: I don't know what type `string` is in that `cs50.h` but as I can see the error is that you are passing a `char**` . Try to show us the header  where `string` is defined, or try to pass `*name` to `scanf`.

Comment: Please don't spam unrelated tags.

Comment: What do you mean by pass *name to scanf? And idk i think string just comes with the ide.

Comment: Because we can't know where that `string` came from and what it is. `scanf` takes address of an allocated `char` array, or a pointer to a `char` memory. `string` is not part of the C standart, so in order to help you, you must describe what `string` is, like peek into it's header.

Comment: Idk where it comes from because if  remove the headers its still knows what string is. i think its part of the ide but i actually dont know. I looked at a youtube vid and i put in his code exactly and it doesnt work for me.

Comment: I added the youtube code to my original post.

Comment: never mind i got it i just had to remove the '&' symbol and it worked. Sorry Its been a while since i last practiced.

Answer (score 1):

As I google that here: https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/src/cs50.h
`string` is declared as `typedef char *string;` so your code has 2 problems.

1. You are not allocating a memory for `string`, which will probably cause you a crash after compiling.
2. You are not using `scanf` correctly. You should pass the `string` variable directly, not by it's address.

Comment: I got it to work in a different way by using char.

Comment: I appreciated the help, turns out im just dumb and forgot that in order to use 'string' i have to use the cs50 header and put "string name = get_string("Whats your name? ");

Comment: Always check your 3rd party headers to see the interfaces and the data structures of your libraries.

Comment: I will. and again thank you. Appreciate it.

Comment: Make sure to flag the topic as solved also.